# Drizzle ORM select return string that isn't a column

Tags: node.js, typescript, drizzle

I have a SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 'car' AS type, model FROM car
      UNION
   SELECT 'truck' AS type, model FROM trucks
) vehicles;
```

I want to replicate the `'car' as type` part in Drizzle so I can distinguish the data being returned without adding a column "type" to both tables and having repetitive data.

Tried something like this, but it says a string cannot be assigned to type.

```
const items = db
      .select({
        type: `car`,
        id: cars.id,
      })
```

Is there a way to do this currently?

Comment: Why don't have it in two separate calls and add the type property after SQL is executed.